# Drop down with search feature for over 300k records

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, dropdown, autosuggest

There is a multi select drop down in GUI which has over 300k records. Due to this huge data, GUI was slowing down for more than 5 minutes. I want to

1. introduce a search option which helps to find proper record
2. Reduce loading time - This is my priority.

We have to fetch from 300k records from DB and send to browser which need around 12mb data

I tried to frame it as json data, but still the loading time was same

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sending such amount of data to the browser is maybe not so good idea. Remember that a user will never see all of this.

Comment: Use an auto-complete control instead. A user will never scroll through all of that to find an option

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a case where it doesn't make much sense to send that much data to the client. If your priority is to reduce loading time, you will need to do the processing on the server.

The user's input can be sent to your server in an AJAX request. The auto-complete feature then displays the server's response data. This is a very small amount of data being set back and forth, and it will not impact loading time at all, since it is asynchronous request.

One other concern here is your database performance. It will depend on how many users you typically get. If you have a lot of traffic, it may be necessary to tune your database to optimize it for this scenario. The other option would be to frame the data as JSON and hold it in a static file. If the data doesn't change frequently, or at all, this would be feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But auto complete feature can be implemented in a text box only i believe. I need multi select drop down.

Comment: @minnalprathap the solution to that is to allow the user to select multiple values consecutively - once they have selected a value, display it on the page in another element just below the textbox (and store it in a JS array, if necessary). Then clear the textbox and allow them to search for another value. This is quite a common technique. You don't _need_ a multi-select dropdown, you just haven't used your imagination to think of another way. A multi-select dropdown will never work with this volume of data - it'll be un-usable due to the amount of scrolling required to find anything.

Comment: @ADyson makes sense . Thanks a lot. I will try this approach